# I cannot import matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to implement a Bar graph to a GUI, however when I try to import the `matplotlib` I get the following error

```
import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

This is even though I've successfully installed the `matplotlib` with
`pip install  matplotlib`.

Does anyone have an idea of what my problem could be ?

Comment: Odds are phthonnor Jupyter are from a different env

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/)

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same Python environment?